# How to find matches in website consists of 5 .html pages using search form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a website that consists of 5 .html pages , I have a navigation menu that contain a search form , I want to use this form to find matches in these 5 html pages , How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution would be to use google custom search.